# Nextjs not server side rendered when i wrapped component by auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I using Next.js for SSR, after I try to make authentication for user client by Auth component following to my idea. But I have a problem when **View Source** page, it not loaded as HTML tag which empty root like **create-react-app**, now it my code in **_app.js**:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { ...pageProps } }) {  
  const { auth } = Component;
  return (
    <>
      {
        auth ?               
          <Auth>
             <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Auth>  
          :
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      }
    </>
  )
  
}
```

Which **Auth component** is:

```
export const Auth = async (props) => {

  const { children } = props;

  const auth = await POST('http://localhost:7000/services/api/auth');

  if (!auth) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>    
  }

  return children
}
```

And the **page** wrapped by auth component is:

```
    export const getServerSideProps = async ctx =>{
      const { id } = ctx.query;
      try {
          const postById = await GET(`http://localhost:7000/services/api/post/${id}`);
          return {
            props: {
              post: postById
            },
          }
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

    export default const DetailPost = (props) => {
      return (
        ...
      )
    }
```

What should I do it for rendered with HTML DOM like server-side-rendering?